# Emacs Lisp: Multiple comment-start values

Tags: emacs, comments

Is it possible to have multiple comment-start strings in an Emacs major mode? I am looking at some VB code, which has both single-quote comments and "REM" comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. C and C++ mode do, for example.

See the Elisp manual, node [Syntax Class Table](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html). This is the relevant part for comment syntax:

> **Comment starters: `<`**
>
> **Comment enders: `>`**
>
> Characters used in various languages to delimit comments.  Human
>        text has no comment characters.  In Lisp, the semicolon (`;`)
>        starts a comment and a newline or formfeed ends one.

(You will need to read more about specifying syntax classes, to configure your own comment behavior.)

FYI, I found this node of the manual by using `i` in the manual: `i comment TAB`.